# How to disable event sounds with gsettings in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, sound, events

I have an install script that I run after fresh installations to install apps, mount network drives and make changes to several configurations to my liking. One of them is disabling the event sounds.

Up until now I have used this command to achieve that:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

However, with 18.04 this command doesn't work anymore. Anyone know which schema and key to use now?

Comment: Maybe you find the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444869/262708.

Comment: @abu_bua Thank you for taking time to answer. The command suggested in the linked answer is basically the same as I have used before, but since 18.04 doesn't provide the wanted result anymore. I haven't tried the other solution, copying the config file, as that is not really the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable events using gsettings, instead it's saved in pulseaudio's TDB files.

Using tdbtools (`apt install tdb-tools`), you can update the setting in the database:

```
cd ~/.config/pulse

# Create a back-up in case anything bricks
cp *-stream-volumes.tdb stream-volumes.bup

# Get the entry and update it
entry=$(tdbdump *-stream-volumes.tdb | grep "sink-input-by-media-role:event" -a1 | tail -n1 | cut -d'"' -f2)
tdbtool *-stream-volumes.tdb store "sink-input-by-media-role:event" "${entry/00101/00111}"
```

This updates the value for the key "sink-input-by-media-role:event" to mute the system sounds (101 → 111). In my case, these are the values in both states:

```
On:  B\011m\01\00v\01\00\01\00\00101talsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo\000N
Off: B\011m\01\00v\01\00\01\00\00111talsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo\000N
```

Your values are most probably different, but the value needed to replace remains the same.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the activities panel and type in sound.  Click on it and choose sound effects. Click OFF for alert volume (currently denoted as ON).

Comment: Welcome yum to askubuntu! Thank you for your answer, but the OP (original poster) would like to disable **event sounds**, while you suggest only how to mute alerts . Further the OP is looking for an **commandline** solution, since he want to use it in a bash script.